# How to Search Between MIN and MAX in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I know that in MySQL the query looks something like this...

```
SELECT id 
    FROM listings 
    WHERE id  IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM listings
      WHERE price between 200 and 500
    );
```

In Laravel Query I tried...

```
Listing::select('listings.*')
    ->whereBetween('price', [200, 500])
    ->groupBy('listings.id')
    ->orderBy('listings.id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(1000);
```

It only shows me one result. Did I go wrong somewhere? Thank you for your help!

Comment: show your laravel query full

Comment: what is error you got?

Comment: just updated for full query

Comment: @sanduniYW no Error

Comment: what is your expected result for the query

Comment: SELECT id FROM listings WHERE price between 200 and 500; will do the same query with that you provided. And is there a reason you use groupBy function for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
Listing:: where(price, '>=', 200 )
                 ->where(price, '<=', 500 )
                 ->groupBy('id')
                 ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                 ->paginate(1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Listing::select('listings.*')
                 ->whereRaw("(listings.price <= ? AND listings.price >= ?) ", [500, 200])
                 ->groupBy('listings.id')
                 ->orderBy('listings.id', 'desc')
                 ->paginate(1000);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if in older versions of laravel you have to specify the table's name before each columns if you use eloquent and call the model itself...anyway I added "listings." before the price, try with it maybe that was missing

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.